# DIV tag creating new line in php

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to style results from database but when I echo `<div>` it is creating new line after each result. How can I force the div not to create a new line?

```
.message {
    border:2px solid;
    background-color:white;
}
```

php

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '');
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages where from_user = ?  ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo"<div class='message'>";

    echo $row['to_user'];

    echo"</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create new DIVs every time. Every div by default starts with a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `<span>` instead of `<div>`

`<span>` are already inline tags where `<div>` are blocks by default, which create a new line for the content in it.

Comment: Thanks Nightfirecat. I was trying to edit that right as you did!

Answer (score 0):

you can either display the div as `inline-block` or set `float: [left|right]`

Using inline style

```
style="display: inline-block;"

style="float: left;"
```

using css

```
.message {
   display: inline-block;
}

.message {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Why inline style instead of in the CSS?

Comment: It just seemed strange that you would suggest inline style when the question already uses CSS.

Comment: okay this works but what if I want to have a `<br/>` tag so the rows will be inside the div?

Comment: you can break rows using other methods without using `<br/>` like using `clear: both`

Answer (score 0):

```
.message{
        border:2px solid;
        background-color:white;
        float:left;
        }
```

try with above css will display in one line

Answer (score 0):

Use css property display:inline-block
e.g.

```
.message{
  border:2px solid;
  background-color:white;
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

It will arrange your messages linearly.