# Displaying rows inside a div

Tags: php, html, css

I had asked this question but didn't clarify what I wanted. I want the rows from table be displayed inside the div. I just want to break each row inside the div so while the div is the main container with background then the rows should align vertical, without creating another border. just the whole thing inside the div.

```
       .message{
        border:2px solid;
        background-color:white;
        float:left;
        }
```

php

```
 $user = $_SESSION['username'];
 $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '');
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages where from_user = ?  ");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
 $stmt->execute();


$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo"<div class='message'>";


echo $row['to_user']."<br/>";

echo"</div>";

}
```

Comment: Don't ask essentially the same question twice. Clarify your original question.

Comment: sorry my bad I will keep in mind that the next time.

Comment: You can keep it in mind this time. Delete the question and edit your other one.

Comment: @Barmar yes it is I already stated that.

Comment: Yes what is? You mean the duplicate? That's an automatically created comment that comes from submitting a close-vote.

Comment: Not that one, I wrote "I had asked this question..."

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18265575/1646111 he answered you.

Comment: @Akam Yes he did but it isn't what I wanted. See the below answer that's it.

Comment: no, its you that not understood that answer, he said: you create new divs every time, so, its logically means you need to move the opening and closing `<div>` tags to outside the loop :)

Comment: I know you wrote that. Then you wrote "yes it is", and I was wondering what that was in response to, since I never asked a question. I surmised that it was a response to the "possible duplicate" comment, which was generated automatically when I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So div class="message" is the main container that you wnat all the content to be in rows inside of?

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo"<div class='message'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row['to_user']."<br/>";

}

echo"</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the while loop; add the html to the print out, ie:

```
echo '<div class="message-line">'.$row['to_user'].'</div>';
```

This will make each row from the table a new line within the message container. It will also allow you to style it to your hearts content later on.